# mysql complex where query

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to solve this problem for past few days any help would be appreciated.

I have a Return item which have term1 in taxonomy1 AND term2 in taksonomy2.

This is my query:

```
SELECT items.*
FROM (`items`)
LEFT JOIN `rel_taxonomy` ON `rel_taxonomy`.`item_id` = `items`.`id`
LEFT JOIN `terms_taxonomy` ON `terms_taxonomy`.`terms_taxonomy_id` = `rel_taxonomy`.`terms_taxonomy_id`
LEFT JOIN `terms` ON `term`.`id` = `terms_taxonomy`.`term_id`
WHERE (items.org =  '2')  AND  ( ((terms_taxonomy.taxonomy =  '1') AND (term.pojam  LIKE '%term1%')) AND ((terms_taxonomy.taxonomy =  '2') AND (term.pojam  LIKE '%term2%')))  
GROUP BY `items`.`id`
```

If I replace the line:

```
WHERE (items.org =  '2')  AND  ( ((terms_taxonomy.taxonomy =  '1') AND (term.pojam  LIKE '%term1%')) AND ((terms_taxonomy.taxonomy =  '2') AND (term.pojam  LIKE '%term2%')))
```

with the following (replacing an AND with an OR):

```
WHERE (items.org =  '2')  AND  ( ((terms_taxonomy.taxonomy =  '1') AND (term.pojam  LIKE '%term1%')) OR((terms_taxonomy.taxonomy =  '2') AND (term.pojam  LIKE '%term2%')))
```

everything works fine. But I still need AND.

Table scheme

```
items
id | title | org

rel_taxonomy
item_id | terms_taxonomy_id

terms_taxonomy
terms_taxonomy_id | terms_id | taxsonomy 

terms
id | term
```

so I'm trying to get item which have term1 in taxonomy1 AND term2 in taksonomy2.

Comment: It isn't very clear what you are trying to ask here.

Comment: Right - don't expect us to reverse-engineer the details of what you are asking from non-working code.  You should at least explain your tables schema.

Comment: Can you please show some sample input data and output as you want it to be?

Comment: sorry guys here is more info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `OR` and add a `HAVING` clause

```
 SELECT i.id
 FROM items i
 LEFT JOIN rel_taxonomy rt ON rt.item_id = i.id
 LEFT JOIN terms_taxonomy tt ON tt.terms_taxonomy_id = rt.terms_taxonomy_id
 LEFT JOIN terms t ON t.id = tt.term_id
 WHERE i.org =  '2'
 AND 
 ( 
        (tt.taxonomy =  '1' AND t.pojam  LIKE '%term1%') 
     OR (tt.taxonomy =  '2' AND t.pojam  LIKE '%term2%')
 )  
 GROUP BY i.id
 having count(distinct tt.taxonomy) = 2
```

Comment: @Mlajo: Any feedback on my answer?

Comment: And change the left joins to inner joins - the where clause is excluding rows with unrelated records.